# How do I create a new XElement for each </br> tag in XML in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, foreach

My XML contains data as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repub>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<sec>
<title>First Title</title>
<break name="1-1"/>
<h1><page num="1"/>First Heading</h1>
<bl>This is another text</bl>
<fig><img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
<p>This<br/> again is<br/> a paragraph</p>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

It contains a `<p>` tag with multiple `<br/>` tags. I want to create a new `<p>` for each `<br/>`.

What I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repub>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<sec>
<title>First Title</title>
<break name="1-1"/>
<h1><page num="1"/>First Heading</h1>
<bl>This is another text</bl>
<fig><img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
<p>This</p>
<p>again is</p>
<p>a paragraph</p>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

I don't know how to proceed.

What I have tried:

I am trying to approach it by using the following method:

```
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("p"))
{
    if (item.Elements("br").Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var br in item.Elements("br"))
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> brs = doc.Descendants("br").ToList();

            for (int i = brs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                brs[i].ReplaceWith(new XElement("br", new XElement("p", new object[] {brs[i].Attributes(), brs[i].Nodes()})));
            }


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This just replaces the `<br/>` tags to `<p/>` tags. What I wanted is in the question and this does not achieve it.

Comment: I modified one line.  The sample output doesn't agree with the words in the request.

Comment: `<p>This is a value that needs <br><p /></br>to be separated by break<br><p /></br>tags into separate paragraph <br><p /></br>tags in multiple lines.</p>`. This is what I got.